# HTML tags in Formula field are displayed randomly as HTML markup (escaped)

Tags: formula, html

We created a field of type "Formula" with Formula Return Type "Text" and the Advanced Formula (using the BR function):

```
'Line1' + BR() + 'Line2' + BR() + 'Line3'
```

This field was included in Compact Layout and in Page Layout.
The field is sometimes (randomly (!)) displayed correctly (3 lines with line breaks, also see the first screenshot)

```
Line1
Line2
Line3
```

and sometimes as HTML markup (also see the second screenshot):

```
Line1<br>Line2<br>Line3
```

The same happens using the IMAGE function or any other function generating HTML markup.

In case of correct display, the HTML source for this snippet is

```
<p class="slds-text-body--regular  slds-truncate" data-aura-rendered-by="307:719;a">
    <span data-aura-rendered-by="298:719;a">
        Line1<br data-aura-rendered-by="300:719;a">Line2<br data-aura-rendered-by="300:719;a">Line3
    </span>
</p>
```

In case of incorrect display, the HTML source is

```
<p class="slds-text-body--regular  slds-truncate" data-aura-rendered-by="307:719;a">
    <span data-aura-rendered-by="298:719;a" class="uiOutputText" data-aura-class="uiOutputText">
        Line1&lt;br&gt;Line2&lt;br&gt;Line3
    </span>
</p>
```

- We're using a sandbox with the Winter'18 release
- the same happens in the production environment and
- both in Lightning Experience and Salesforce classic
- in all browsers

Is this a known problem? How can this be fixed?

[image: Correct display]

[image: Incorrect display]

Comment: Is it the same in all browsers?

Comment: I think the issue is probably indeed the browser that sometimes generates the layout themselves, interpreting it as rich text and otherwise just as text - in which case you see the HTML.  A possible workaround (I think) is to define a rich text field and fill it with that data :)

Comment: @KoenCertyn In this case rich text field works, but not in case of referencing other fields (the 'TestN' strings are just to simplify the problem description).

Comment: You can use workflow rules/PB to complete the reference to the other fields to complete the rich text field, no?

Comment: @KoenCertyn Ok, I've to look at this workflow rules/PB functionality, currently I'm not familiar with this. Formula field is just simple to use, so if there is a solution I would prefer using formulas.

Comment: @KoenCertyn Rich Text Area as field type is no option as Rich Text Area is not supported in Compact Layout

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this issue still comes up every now and then in random places.

For anybody looking for a workaround, you can create a **Custom Label** (*say* `New_Line`) and use it in the concerned formulas.

The value of this custom label should be as follows.

```
<
>
```

The label needs to have the dummy starting end ending characters (that is, `<` and `>`) because all leading and trailing whitespace gets removed.

This custom label can then be used in a formula field as follows.

```
"Line1" & MID($Label.New_Line,2,1) & "Line2" & MID($Label.New_Line,2,1) & "Line3"
```